# intellij idea disconnected from GIT

Tags: intellij-idea

I have a problem, my intellij idea crashed on memory so I restared it, but when it opened again all my projects have been disconected from git, now it looks that I work only locally, because there is no branches, commit possibility, nothing, how can I recconect it without cloning again and losing my changes?

Answer (score 0):

Go to the VCS menu at the top and select the "Enable Version Control Integration" option
In the dialog box that appears, you should see Git as an option. Select Git and click "OK" to enable Git integration for the project as below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was that during crashing on memory, IDEA turned of the plugin for git, so after enabling again the git plugin everything to start work again.